# Issues with adding packages after migration to plugin DSL grade

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

I recently upgraded to flutter 3.19 version as a result it asked me to change the gradle to use plugin dsl[https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply]. However, I'm trying to add flutter_local_notifications package in my project which states to make changes in the build.gradles. I issue its pointing is adding 'com.android.tools' as its stated in documentation to add as following:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
    }
```

My gradle files:
Settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.tools' version "7.3.1" apply false
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version "4.3.15" apply false
}

include ":app"
```

android/build.gradle:

```
ext {
        compileSdkVersion   = 34                // or higher / as desired
       targetSdkVersion    = 33                // or higher / as desired
        minSdkVersion       = 21                // Required minimum
        appCompatVersion    = "1.4.2"           // or higher / as desired
        playServicesLocationVersion = "21.0.1"  // or higher / as desired
    }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

android/app/build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
    id 'com.android.tools'
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')

if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
               targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {

        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            shrinkResources false
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0'
    implementation 'io.radar:sdk:3.8.+'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10"

}
```

However, as the steps mentioned are according to the old gradle system. Im facing problem in being able to add the plugin. However, I tried adding the changes according to the plugin dsl method. Im getting an error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file '/StudioProjects/project/android/settings.gradle' line: 33

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.android.tools', version: '7.3.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (None of the included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.tools:com.android.tools.gradle.plugin:7.3.1')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Google
    MavenRepo
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```